# Why does conversion operator call copy constructor twice when equivalent function calls it only once?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am running in Visual Studio 2017.  My program defines a class with a conversion operator as well as defining an equivalent conversion function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T, class U>
struct A
{
    A();
   ~A() { std::cout << "In A destructor\n"; delete n; }
    A(T i);
    A(const A& a);
    operator A<U,T>();
    T* n;
};

template<class T, class U>
A<T,U>::A()
{
    n = new T;
   *n = 0;
}

template<class T, class U>
A<T,U>::A(T i)
{
    n = new T;
   *n = i;
}

template<class T, class U>
A<T,U>::A(const A& a)
{
    std::cout << "In A copy constructor\n";
    n = new T;
   *n = *(a.n);
}

template<class T, class U>
A<T,U>::operator A<U,T>()
{
    A<U,T> aut;
    *(aut.n) = static_cast<U>(*n);
    return aut;
}

template<class T, class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A<T,U>& a)
{
    os << *(a.n);
    return os;
}

template<class T, class U>
A<U,T> convert(A<T,U>& a)
{
    A<U,T> c;
   *(c.n) = static_cast<U>(*(a.n));
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    A<int, unsigned int> a1(-1);
    std::cout << a1 << "\n";

    A<unsigned int, int> a2 = A<unsigned int, int>(a1);
    std::cout << a2 << "\n";

    A<unsigned int, int> a3 = convert(a1);
    std::cout << a3 << "\n";

    std::cout << "Press ENTER to exit\n";
    getline(std::cin, s);
}
```

The output when I compile without optimization is

```
-1
In A copy constructor
In A destructor
In A copy constructor
In A destructor
4294967295
In A copy constructor
In A destructor
4294967295
Press ENTER to exit
```

The copy constructor is called twice after the program calls the conversion operator, but only once after it calls the function `convert()` which does the same thing.  It seems that in the call to the conversion operator the program is creating a temporary object that the function `convert()` does not cause to be made.  Why is there a difference between the number of times the program calls the copy constructor after the call to the conversion operator and the number of times the program calls the copy constructor after the call to `convert()`?

Comment: I can not reproduce. It seems it depends on the compiler and its optimization options.

Comment: I suspect that it's  because `A<unsigned int, int>(a1)` is not an explicit conversion using the conversion operator, but an object creation *after* an implicit conversion. (But I can't find anything about it in The Standard, so it might not be the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The definition

```
A<unsigned int, int> a2 = A<unsigned int, int>(a1);
```

is really

```
A<unsigned int, int> a2 = A<unsigned int, int>(a1.operator A<unsigned int, int>());
```

which is equivalent to

```
A<unsigned int, int> temporary_compiler_generated_object = a1.operator A<unsigned int, int>();
A<unsigned int, int> a2 = temporary_compiler_generated_object;
```

Here the copy-constructor of the temporary object as well as `a2` needs to be invoked.

Comment: Why doesn't the function `convert()` create a second temporary object in exactly the same way?

Comment: @TRPh When you use `convert` you are creating a single object through copy-construction (`a3`). When you create `a2` you're implicitly create *two* objects through copy-construction.

Comment: Obviously.  But why?

Comment: @TRPh `A<unsigned int, int>(a1)` isn't a cast, it creates a temporary object. This temporary object will be copy-initialized. *Then* you also create the `a2` object, using copy-initialization from the temporary object.